# Counting median of character variables

Tags: sas, median, proc

I have the following data set:

```
Date       Company      State
Jan05     Coca-Cola      TX     
Jan05     Coca-Cola      TX 
Jan05     Coca-Cola      DE     
Jan05     Apple          DE 
Jan05     Apple          DE 
Jan05     Apple          DE
Jan05     Microsoft      DE
Feb05     McDonald       MD 
Feb05     McDonald       MD 
Feb05     McDonald       MD
Feb05     McDonald       MD 
Feb05     McDonald       MD 
Feb05     Microsoft      MD   
Jan06     Apple          DE
Jan06     Apple          DE
Jan06     Apple          DE
Jan06     Apple          DE 
Jan06     Apple          DE 
Jan06     Apple          DE
Jan06     Apple          DE    
Feb06     McDonald       MD 
Feb06     McDonald       MD 
Feb06     McDonald       MD
Feb06     McDonald       MD 
Feb06     McDonald       MD 
Feb06     Lenova         MD 
Feb06     Lenova         MD
Jan07     Apple          DE
Jan07     Apple          DE
Jan07     Apple          DE 
Jan07     Microsoft      DE     
Jan07     Lenovo         DE  
Jan07     Apple          DE
Jan07     Apple          DE
Feb07     TJmax          TX
Feb07     TJMax          TX
Feb07     TJMax          TX
Feb07     TJMax          MD
Feb07     TMax           MD
Feb07     TJMax          MD
Feb07     TJMax          MD
```

What I am trying to do is calculate a 12 month median growth rate per Company from Jan05 to Jan06, then from Jan06 to Jan07, February05 to February06, then from February06 to February07 for each State and so on for the other dates BUT only if the company is available on both dates. I obviously cannot calculate a median growth rate for a company that doesn't exist on both dates. For example, I can calculate the median growth rate of McDonald from Feb05 to Feb06, and Lenovo from Jan06 to Jan07 for the state of MD. The median number is basically the number of times each Company is mentioned (sort of like a count variable).

What I have thought of doing so far: I could create a separate data set for each State, and then create a count variable that calculates the number of times each Company is mentioned and take the median of it. But I assume there is a more efficient way to do this in a do loop.

What is the best way to do this in SAS?

Comment: I'm confused. Can you add the dataset you would want as output from the test data you showed?  A median is not a count, and you can't find the median of a character variable.

Comment: You've already asked a very similar or identical question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661121/compare-and-keep-character-observations-that-are-the-same). Please explain how this one is different.

Comment: @Quentin.  The reason why i want a count variable is that because there is no other way to do the median than to count the number of times each company is mentioned. So then I'll take the median of each count. My ultimate goal is calculate a median growth rate per company and for that, I can only have the companies that are present on the months that are 12 months apart.

Comment: @user2916331 suggest you show the dataset you would want as output.